# Route 53 failover health check sync with load balancer health check

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-route53, high-availability, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, failover

We have application with route53 failover type. Currently i have two api's in two with load balancers attached.

1. primary
2. secondary

Both apis have health check url **HTTP:80/health.**

Timeout is **10 seconds**.

Amount of time between health checks of an individual instance is **15 seconds**.

The number of consecutive successful health checks required to designate the instance as healthy is **2 requests**

Finally health check failure threshold for route53 is 10 and request interval is 30sec.

Everything works fine, but some times when one of my api is down, we have to face average downtime of approx 5 to 10 minutes which is not bearable.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.